# Adding a parent of same type to and entity results in stackoverflow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I'm making this MVC Razor website. And it required Categories:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
      // The category can have a parent opject of type category which on his 
      // Turn should get children.
    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }


    public CategoryModel ToModel()
    {
        CategoryModel model = new CategoryModel();
        model.Id = this.Id;
        model.Name = this.Name;
        model.Parent =  this.Parent==null?null:this.Parent.ToModel();
        model.Description = this.Description;
        model.Children = new List<CategoryModel>();
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
           model.Children.Add(child.ToModel());

        }

        return model;
    }

    public static Category FromModel(CategoryModel model)
    {
        Category cat = new Category();
        cat.Id = model.Id;
        cat.Description = model.Description;
        cat.Name = model.Name;

        return cat;
    }
}
```

Now to do so In my view i have a dropdownlist of all Categories that do not have a parent (main categories) and it returns an int: 'Model.SelectedParent' which is -1 if none is selected.

This is the post action from my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CategoryModel categorymodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Category cat = Category.FromModel(categorymodel);
            db.Categories.Add(cat);
            db.SaveChanges();
            if (categorymodel.SelectedParent != -1)
            {

                cat.Parent = db.Categories.Find(categorymodel.SelectedParent);
                db.Entry(cat).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        categorymodel.PossibleParents = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        categorymodel.PossibleParents.Add(-1, "None");
        foreach (var parent in db.Categories.Where(x => x.Parent == null))
        {
            categorymodel.PossibleParents.Add(parent.Id, parent.Name);
        }

        return View(categorymodel);
    }
```

Now when I create a category without a parent everything goes fine and i can add multiple without a parent. But as soon as I try to create one with a parent I get a Stackoverflow.  I'm really stuck.

So can any of you help me fix this problem?

I would also like an explaination about why the stackoverflow is thrown (I know what it is, I just don't know why it's been thrown now)?

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: It's not a good idea to convert your Model to ViewModel and vice versa inside the model. That should be done in your Controller.

Comment: @jlew It hardly gives a stacktrace. The call stack gives '[External code]'

Comment: @ataravati Could this be part of the problem? Because as soon as it has occured all my other pages (which normally loaded fine) also give stackoverflow errors after running.

Comment: It could be. What do you need the CategoryModel anyway? Why don't you use Category instead?

Comment: @ataravati because the categorymodel holds unneccesary data for the database.

Comment: The CategoryModel class you have posted here has the same properties as the Category class.

Comment: That isn't true, the viewmodel holds possible parents and the selectedvalue of which parent. I like to keep my context models separated from my view models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have figured it out with the help of [ataravati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781366/ataravati). 
The problem lies in the `Category.ToModel();` function.

```
public CategoryModel ToModel()
{
    CategoryModel model = new CategoryModel();
    model.Id = this.Id;
    model.Name = this.Name;
    model.Parent =  this.Parent==null?null:this.Parent.ToModel();  // reference one
    model.Description = this.Description;
    model.Children = new List<CategoryModel>();
    foreach (var child in Children)
    {
       model.Children.Add(child.ToModel()); // reference two

    }

    return model;
}
```

As soon as the class has a parent. I calls `parent.ToModel()` where it's starts to create the parent. But while creating the parent it tries to also create the childs, thus comming back to making a model for the same item as first but in a higher stack. When again trying to create a model of the child it also tries to make a model of the parent etc etc......

And I think that is what caused the stackoverflow.